# angular 13 - different host only for assets

Tags: angular

lets say i have a website https://example.com that im deploying my application to , but all my assets is in anouther domain  https://assets.example.com

so if i have an image [image] i need it to be after build to [image]

also need to support css urls like

```
background-image: url('/assets/img.png');
```

is there an easy way to do it in angular?

I need the domain to be added dynamically in the build.

i tried

```
ng build --base-href https://example.com --deploy-url https://assets.example.com
```

but it didnt work and deploy-url is deprecated

Comment: Just use the full url? `background-image: url('https://assets.example.com/assets/img.png');`

Comment: I have an existing project with thousands of URLs, and I want to find an easier solution than that...

Comment: Well that is not hard, if you ask me. I use webstorm and I can easily ReplaceAll `url('/assets/'` findings by `url('https://assets.example.com/assets/` in the whole project with a filter on css files. What is stopping you from using such a ReplaceAll function of your used IDE?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need to add the domains dynamically

Answer (score 0):

create a property, which holds the assets url and instead of using css class, use style directive to set the background image.
for example:

```
[style.backgroundImage]=`url(${assetsUrl}/assets/img.png)`
```

Comment: yes, it would work, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do it without code change, only in the build.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do it in the build